# How to delete an array inside a hash

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I have a hash that looks like this:

```
my_hash = {"positions"=>[[2, 3, 13, 56], [2, 3, 13]]}
```

I would like to delete the first array inside of the hash:

```
wanted_hash == {"positions"=> [2, 3, 13]}
```

I tried:

```
wanted_hash = my_hash.values[0].pop
```

but this removes the wrong array. I'm not sure why, but it removes `[2,3,13]`.

Comment: Here's a way to do that without mutating the original hash: `my_hash.merge(my_hash) { |*,n| n.last } #=> {"positions"=>[2, 3, 13]}`. I prefer   @Sebastian's solution, but this may be useful if it is necessary to support Ruby versions prior to 2.4, when [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) may its debut.

Comment: Deleting the first inner array would result in `[[2, 3, 13]]` – do you also want to flatten the outer array? Or maybe replace the outer array by its 2nd element?

Comment: `my_hash['positions'] = my_hash['positions'][1]` might be what you are looking for – it assigns to key `'positions'` the first element of the array it is holding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `transform_values` and select the second element from the array in `positions`:

```
my_hash = {"positions"=>[[2, 3, 13, 56], [2, 3, 13]]}
wanted_hash = my_hash.transform_values { |value| value[1] }
# {"positions"=>[2, 3, 13]}
```

Notice it doesn't modify `my_hash`, it returns a new object.

Answer (score 3):

`pop` is removing the last element of an array. Try `shift` instead.

Comment: `shift` returns something like `[[2, 3, 13]]`.

Comment: Yes, indeed `shift` is mutating the double array

Comment: `shift` returns the element that shifted from the array but if you don't assign it to anything then Ruby will ignore it. Some demonstration code would help the OP visualize how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Carried out this series of steps in irb. This is assuming that you want to mutate my_hash:

```
my_hash = {"positions"=>[[2, 3, 13, 56], [2, 3, 13]]}
# => {"positions"=>[[2, 3, 13, 56], [2, 3, 13]]} 
my_hash["positions"].shift
# => [2, 3, 13, 56] 
my_hash
# => {"positions"=>[[2, 3, 13]]} 
my_hash["positions"].flatten!
# => [2, 3, 13] 
my_hash
# => {"positions"=>[2, 3, 13]}
```

So, it comes down to:

```
my_hash["positions"].shift
my_hash["positions"].flatten!
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with non-destructive `each_with)object` method:

`my_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[1]}`.

If you use ruby version < 2.4.0 (where `transform_values` method was introduced) this could help.